# Start Date and Transaction Date of PayPal

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I am confused about the Email Notification of PayPal after my Transaction. Because I have a Monthly recurring setup then I subscribe to PayPal on July 27, 2020, but based on the Email Notification my Payment Start Date is July 28, 2020, but then when I check my Transaction Date in my PayPal business account they billed me July 27, 2020, at 8:09 PM. It is normal in PayPal that the Email Notification said that my Payment Start is July 28, 2020, but they billed me on July 27, 2020?

Please see the below image.

[image]

Thank you so much.

This is a copy of the first email of PayPal after my subscription registration.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Subscription profiles bill in a batch that is independent of the initial creation time.

For profiles with an immediate start date, when that first batch bills will usually be within 24 hours of when the profile itself was set up.  This usually ends up being the next day, so it showed "28"

But because of the checkout's early time and the forward timezone (GMT+8), apparently you were already in the day it would first bill ("27", later at 8:09 pm) -- and so displaying a first payment date of 27+1 was wrong for this case.

Comment: Sir, I am confused in the email and in the transaction date because after my subscription the email notification from PayPal my first payment is on the date of my subscription which is July 27, 2020, but as you said in my previous question the first payment would be on the following day because PayPal has a batch. But based on the email notification PayPal sent me is my first payment is July 27, 2020. So I'm a little bit confused in the dates given by PayPal.

Comment: I post the first email of PayPal after may subscription registration.

Comment: Subscriptions bill in batch. Usually it's the next day, so it showed "28". Sometimes due to the time zone and time of checkout it isn't the next day and can bill sooner, so this "28" was wrong here.

Comment: So you mean the email of PayPal saying that Payment Start Date is 28 is wrong? Also according to email also my next payment due on August 28, 2020?

Comment: Is it an email? I'm not sure that's an email. During checkout the payment was shown to be 28 but it entered the batch and billed sooner.  This is good unless you like waiting for the next batch which would be a further 24 hours later on the 28th at 8pm.  Future payments will enter the batch on the 28th.

Comment: Yes, the two with a logo of PayPal are email notification after my subscription registration and after they billed me. So I get confused because of the two emails from Paypal.

Comment: Oh okay, the 2nd email is on the receiving account after it ran the payment in the earlier 27th batch.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218731/discussion-between-mark-leo-jacinto-and-preston-phx).